# how to to obtain a determine values from a foreach

Tags: php, mysql, php-7

I am creating a user tree to save it in a .json file, but I can not find the way to read the third-party users in the secondary users

through a foreach that the secondary users of mysql read me but it does not align them within the third ones
my tables are

1.(username=juan    referedby=none)

2.(username=jose    referedby=juan)

3.(username=alberto    referedby=juan)

4.(username=fernando    referedby=jose)

```
`` php


$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username FROM affiliateuser WHERE referedby = '$actualuser'");
$stmt->execute();
$array = [];
foreach ($stmt->get_result() as $row)
{
    $referedby[] = $row['username'];

}
$string = '';
$string2 = '';
foreach ($referedby as $key => $secundaryusers){
}` ``
```

I hope the result gives me something like that.

```
    { "name": "juan ", "children": [ { "name ": "jose", "children": [{ "name": "fernando", "children": [] }] } { "name": "alberto", "children": [] } ] },
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please describe your tables and explain how they relate. It is unclear what you mean by "secondary users" and "third-party" users.

Comment: is an example, because I need to create their "children" and the children of their "children" through [foreach] to read their children and their "grandchildren"

Comment: Edit your question and improve the explanation. Provide some data examples for your tables. We are happy to help, but you must help yourself first.

Comment: @ryantxr better ?

Comment: Describe your table by using `DESC affiliateuser` and add that to the question. Then  add some sample data and put that in the question.

Comment: the code has been edited

Comment: Look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56103375/user-hierarchy-query

Comment: Yes, I want something like that but in json

Comment: By explicitly showing the table definition and corresponding sample data, someone could make that table themselves and test a solution before providing it.

Comment: sorry i am desperate

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question, especially about the expected output. If you are looking for children of children, where do you gather them? Probably you want to use another SQL query for this?

Comment: send pm facebook.com/danckard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is to make a PHP structure that has the data as it would exist in JSON then convert that structure to JSON using json_encode().

If you look at `class User` it represents a user and all the descendants.
If I can populate it with all the data then converting it into JSON is easy.

Note that each user in the table has a parent which is stored in the column `referredby_id`. This is the primary key of the parent user.
You can change this to be the username if you want so long as the username in the table is guaranteed to be unique.
To do this, change the type of the referredby_id column to VARCHAR. If the amount of data is large, then index the username table.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `affilitateuser` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `referredby_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Data:

```
INSERT INTO `affilitateuser` (`id`, `username`, `referredby_id`) VALUES
(1, 'sarah', NULL),
(2, 'james', 1),
(3, 'tom', 2),
(4, 'natalie', 3),
(5, 'juan', NULL),
(6, 'jose', 5),
(7, 'alberto', 5),
(8, 'fernando', 5),
(9, 'camila', 8),
(10, 'sean', 9),
(11, 'scotty', 9),
(12, 'robert', 9),
(13, 'montgomery', 12),
(14, 'jessie', 13),
(15, 'cole', 13),
(16, 'cary', 14),
(17, 'porter', 14),
(18, 'sandra', 5),
(19, 'lily', 6);
```

Code:

```
// A class to represent nodes on a tree
class User
{
    public $name;
    public $children = [];
    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
    // Add a child to this User
    public function addChild($name)
    {
        $u = new User($name);
        $this->children[] = $u;
        // return the newly created object so we can use it later.
        return $u;
    }
}

// Class that does the extracting
class UserTreeExtractor
{
    protected $conn; // keep the database connection

    public function run()
    {
        $this->connect();
        // Extract Juan's tree
        // print_r($this->tree(5));
        // Save the JSON to a string
        $jsonString = json_encode($this->tree(5), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        // Write it out to a file
        file_put_contents('output.json', $jsonString);
    }
    // { "name": "juan ", "children": [ { "name ": "jose", "children": [{ "name": "fernando", "children": [] }] } { "name": "alberto", "children": [] } ] },

    /**
     * Gets the children and downstream descendants for a user
     */
    protected function tree($id)
    {
        // First, get the user
        $sql1 = "SELECT username FROM affilitateuser WHERE id = {$id}";
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql1);
        if ( ! $stmt ) {
            die('query failed');
        }
        $stmt->execute();
        $top = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        // print_r($top); exit();

        // Now get the all descendents
        $sql = "SELECT  id, username, referredby_id 
        FROM    (SELECT * FROM affilitateuser
        ORDER BY referredby_id, id) users_sorted,
        (SELECT @pv := '{$id}') initialisation
        WHERE   find_in_set(referredby_id, @pv)
        AND     LENGTH(@pv := CONCAT(@pv, ',', id))";
        // "SELECT username FROM `affiliateuser` WHERE referedby_id = {$id}"
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $children = [];
        $tree = new User($top['username']);
        // Keep an index of where the objects are stored
        // so we can find them later to attach their children.
        $index[$id] = $tree;
        $parent = null;
        foreach ($stmt->get_result() as $row)
        {
            if ( isset($index[$row['referredby_id']]) ) {
                $new = $index[$row['referredby_id']]->addChild($row['username']);
                $index[$row['id']] = $new; // put the new user into the index
            } else {
                // referred by some user that does not exist
                die("Referred by non-existent user");
            }
            $children[] = ['username' => $row['username'], 'id' => $row['id'], 'referredby_id' => $row['referredby_id']];
        }
        return $tree;
    }
    // Connect to the database
    protected function connect()
    {
        // Change the connection credentials as needed.
        $this->conn = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "app", "aaaa", "sss"); 
        if( ! $this->conn ) { 
            die("Database Connection Failed: ".mysql_error()); 
        }
    }
}

$obj = new UserTreeExtractor;
$obj->run();
```

Comment: a java script ? how to use ?  i only know a lot php...
not exist a method to fill with usernames and referedby usernames extracted from database the json file am put in the code 

$string2 =  "{\"name\": \"$actualuser\", \"children\": [ $string5 ]}";
$string .= "{ \"name\": \"$value\", \"children\": [] }, ";

Comment: This is not JavaScript. This is PHP.

Comment: i fix it now... how to save to a json file ?

Comment: you can send you email or facebook ? to comunicate with you ? i will never forget this

Comment: how to change refferedv_id to username ?